# How to read the WsdlService typeprovider into a local F# class and present as a non-blocking Task for C#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am (extremely) new to F#. I am attempting to download information from a local database to a client application.

On the client side, I am  using the WsdlService typeprovider to access the WCF functions. How is the downloaded class read into a client side F# type?

```
type Wsdl1 = WsdlService<"http://iiii:xxxx/ServiceHost.svc">   // works correctly.

// My New type -- C# compatible.
type MyVisit = {
        lastname : string
        firstname : string
        birthdate : DateTime
        appointment_time : DateTime
        service_time : DateTime
        posting_time : DateTime
        chart_number : int
    }
```

The below works correctly, but returns the visit type as a WSDL type. How do I convert the WSDL type returned by the context to the C# compatible type "Visit" above? The WSDL type has the same field names as "Visit".

```
let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
    async {
        return! context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
    |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I'm thinking some form of " |> Seq.map" is needed, but I can't seem to get it right. The goal here is to provide a non-blocking service available as a Task to the C# code.

Any help is most appreciated.

Update:
This seems to work, is it correct?

```
let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
async {
let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
                                return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
                                    MyVisit.lastname = q.lastname
                                    firstname = q.firstname
                                    birthdate = q.birthdate
                                    appointment_time = q.appointment_time
                                    service_time = q.service_time
                                    posting_time = q.posting_time
                                    chart_number = q.chart_number
                                    })                  
                            }
      |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Comment: Looks fine.  Why do yo need to have C# compatible types?

Comment: @KoenigLear I'm coming from a C# world. I'm thinking, for now at least, I will stay with WPF/C# for the presentation layer and use F# for the client-side proxy to my local intranet. This may vary well change as I learn more. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Your working solution looks good to me! Can you post it as an answer to your own question so that it can be marked as accepted?

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thanks for your response. The first jump into F# seems to be a big one for us just getting started. I will post it as the answer (assuming it is the answer?!).

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my question,

This seems to work correctly:

```
let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
async {
    let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
    return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
        MyVisit.lastname = q.lastname
        firstname = q.firstname
        birthdate = q.birthdate
        appointment_time = q.appointment_time
        service_time = q.service_time
        posting_time = q.posting_time
        chart_number = q.chart_number
        })                  
        }
      |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Thanks to all who helped. I believe it is correct.